# no sorting with JavaScript Client Object Model?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I have the following JSOM code:

```
var query = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Category'/><Value Type='Choice'>ValueA</Value></Eq></Where></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='Value'/><FieldRef Name='Created'/></ViewFields><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy><QueryOptions><RowLimit>6</RowLimit></QueryOptions></View>"
camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery()
camlQuery.set_viewXml(query)
items = list.getItems(camlQuery)
context.load(items)
```

however the items returned don't seem to be in the order I set ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method of setting the query options is a little different in the Client Object Model.
The correct form of your query is:

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Category'/>
                <Value Type='Choice'>ValueA</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Where>
        <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='FALSE' />
        </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
        <FieldRef Name='Value'/>
        <FieldRef Name='Created'/>
    </ViewFields>
    <RowLimit>6</RowLimit>
</View>
```

See this for more details:
[CAML and the Client Object Model](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/caml-and-the-client-object-model/).

Comment: Interessting - I used the CAML Designer (http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/2012/05/12/caml-designer/), which suggested my slightly different CAML; which doesn't seem to work - at least not when using the JSOM.

Comment: Yes the JSCOM uses different format for the CAML. The Caml in my above answer should work with the JSCOM.

Comment: yes, it does - thx!